# Local Uniform Convergence of a series of modified Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, special-functions, bessel-functions

We know that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}-I_0(x))
$$
But how can we show that this convergence is locally uniform?
In particular how can we show
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} e^{-x}I_k(x)
$$
converges locally uniformly to $0$?
I have tried finding some nice bound for $e^{-x}I_k(x)$ such that we end up with something that looks geometric, but I have been unable to get any such bound. Any other methods or suitable bounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [$(10.32.2)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E2), we have
$$
{\rm e}^{ - x} I_k (x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^k \frac{1}{{\Gamma \!\left( {k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}\int_0^\pi  {{\rm e}^{ - x(1 - \cos t)} (\sin t)^{2k} {\rm d}t} 
$$
for any $x\ge 0$ and $k\ge 0$. Accordingly,
$$
\left| {{\rm e}^{ - x} I_k (x)} \right| \le \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^k \frac{1}{{\Gamma \!\left( {k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}} \le \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x}{2}\frac{1}{{(k - 1)!}}\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^{k - 1} 
$$
for any $x\ge 0$ and $k\ge 2$. This gives, for $n\ge 2$,
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - x} I_k (x)} } \right| \le \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x}{2}\sum\limits_{k = n - 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k!}}\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)^k } ,
$$
and it is well known that the power series for $\exp(x/2)$ converges uniformly on compact intervals of the positive reals.